# writing a query and giving a score

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query for the following:

Count the number of transactions in the previous 90 days. Note: This needs to
be averaged out for new members = (No of transactions / Days being a
member) x 90

New members are the one whose DateCreated is between 0 and 90 days from todays date.

Table structure:

```
Column Name         Datatype
---------------------------------
Member_No           nvarchar(255)
Order_No            int
Transaction_Date    datetime 
Net                 money
Date_Created        datetime
```

Also, the final step is after counting the transactions, I need to give a score. So if a member has count more than 8 then give a score of 5.

Following are the ranges:`

```
Transaction count      Score
      >8                  5
      6-8                 4
      4-6                 3
      2-4                 2
      0-2                 1
```

Let me know if any queries

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: Please attached your script.

Comment: Provide some sample data, so that some one can help you quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code works for you  (Not tested because not having Schema.)

```
;WITH RANKS AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS FROM_TR, 2 AS TO_TR, 1 AS SCORE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS FROM_TR, 4 AS TO_TR, 2 AS SCORE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS FROM_TR, 6 AS TO_TR, 3 AS SCORE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS FROM_TR, 8 AS TO_TR, 4 AS SCORE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FROM_TR, NULL AS TO_TR, 5 AS SCORE 

)
, MEMBER_TRANS AS (
SELECT Member_No AS MEMBER_NO
    ,Date_Created AS DATE_CREATED
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT Order_No) ACTUAL_TRANSACT_COUNT
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Date_Created BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, - 90, GETDATE())
                AND GETDATE()
            THEN CAST(
            COUNT(DISTINCT Order_No) / DATEDIFF(DD, Date_Created, GETDATE()) * 90 
            AS INT)
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT Order_No)
        END AS TRANSACT_COUNT
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Transaction_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, - 90, GETDATE())
        AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY Member_No
    ,Date_Created
)

SELECT MT.Member_No,MT.TRANSACT_COUNT, R.SCORE  FROM MEMBER_TRANS MT
INNER JOIN RANKS R ON MT.TRANSACT_COUNT BETWEEN R.FROM_TR 
AND isnull(R.TO_TR,MT.TRANSACT_COUNT)

--Added Extra below code from your comments

UNION ALL

SELECT Member_No,COUNT(DISTINCT Order_No), 1 AS SCORE FROM TABLE1
WHERE Transaction_Date < DATEADD(DD, - 90, GETDATE())
AND  Transaction_Date NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, - 90, GETDATE())
AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY Member_No
```

Comment: This query works for a member between transaction dates of 0-90. If a member has transacted outside that, he should be given a score of 1. What changes need to be done?

Comment: Added Extra UNION ALL in the last for what you have asked. @Shivang

Answer (score 0):

The code will return the desired result as per your requirement.Please find the snapshot of output for below query.
[image]

```
 WITH Mycte
AS
(
Select Member_No,Case when DateDiff(dd,Date_Created,Getdate())>90 then 0 else 1 END AS New_Member
, DateDiff(dd,Date_Created,Getdate()) AS DaysAsMember
,Count(Order_No) TransactionCount from #Sample1
group by Member_No,Date_Created
)
Select Member_No,Case when TransactionCount > 8 THEN 5
        WHEN TransactionCount BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN 4
        WHEN TransactionCount BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN 3
        WHEN TransactionCount BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 2
        WHEN TransactionCount BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 1
        END
        AS Score
From Mycte
```

Comment: Between operator refers to `>=` and `<=`. And 2,4,6,8 are given in different beween case conditions. It might give wrong results

Comment: @ShakeerMirza thanks for noticing...i have updated the code.